# "Speak loudly" vs "speak aloud"

Tags: differences, adverbs

> People, speak **loudly**.
>
> People, speak **aloud**.

These two sentences have the same meaning, don't they? What is the difference between *loudly* and *aloud*?

Comment: I don't think these two mean the same thing, to me. Speaking aloud is the opposite of keeping it to yourself. Speaking loudly is the opposite of speaking in a calm manner.

Comment: I think this question is "Too Basic" for ELU - that's to say "Please include the research you've done" (because we don't think it's adequate). But since I wouldn't take that position if it had been asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), I think it should be *migrated*, not closed.

Answer (score 6):

To speak aloud is to speak in an audible voice so that others can hear you. To speak loudly is to speak with a great volume. To speak up is to talk about your views openly instead of keeping it to yourself. They mean three different things.

Comment: is it even possible to speak inaudibly?

Comment: yes, but low and inaudible are not the same. you can hear low.

Comment: @Brad You can speak internally, though, which is inaudible to anyone but you.

Comment: Internal voices aside, we've been speaking inaudibly all this time. All of us. All this time. Mind = blown.

Comment: How on Earth can ELU tolerate such basic answers, and lacking the slightest of references,  to such basic questions being upvoted?

Comment: Really? 'Answering off-topic questions on the ... site sends the wrong message to the user-base.' _ Dan Bron // 'We do not encourage an answer to an off-topic question.'– Rathony // 'What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer; one that you ... support with authoritative references...'– Matt Gutting // '[W]e should seek to discourage people from providing [basic] answers to [basic] questions ...We all like to be helpful, but the place for that level of help is English Language Learners.' –  FumbleFingers

Comment: So you aren't really interested in the policy here on ELU of trying to redirect such basic questions as the difference between 'speak aloud' and 'speak loudly', or of trying to avoid LMGTFY questions (in this case, let-me-not-bother-to-Google-that-for-you).